Clarification on classical inequality by Hajnal-Juhász
A classical inequality states that if $X$ is a $T_1$ space, then : $$|X| \leq 2^{s(x)\Psi(X)}$$ where $s(X)$ is the spread and $\Psi(X)$ is the pseudo-character of $X$.
An (elegant) short proof can be found on the paper Discrete Subspaces of Topological Spaces (Hajnal, Juhász) - Theorem 6 - or in Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology (Kunen, Vaughan) - Theorem 4.9 (or, more in line with the original proof, sketched at page 21).
Question Clearly, we need to assume some regularity on $X$. For instance, any sufficiently big space endowed with the indiscrete topology will fail to hold the inequality. However, I can't really see where $T_1$ is used in the following argument : Let $\mathcal{B}(x)=\lbrace\mathcal{V}_{x}(\alpha):\alpha\leq\kappa\rbrace$ be a pseudo-basis for $x\in X$, where $\kappa = s(X)\Psi(X)$. Define $$\mathcal{W}_{x}(\alpha,\beta)=\mathcal{V}_{x}(\alpha)\cap\mathcal{V}_{x}(\beta)$$ $$E(\alpha, \beta)=\lbrace\lbrace x,y\rbrace : x\notin\mathcal{W}_{y}(\alpha,\beta), y\notin\mathcal{W}_{x}(\alpha, \beta) \rbrace$$ It seems that the definition of pseudo-basis (without requiring $T_1$ ?!) implies that $[X]^{2}\subset\bigcup_{\alpha,\beta\leq\kappa}E(\alpha,\beta)$. Assuming $|X|>2^{\kappa}$, Erdos-Rado would then imply the existence of some $Y\subset X$ with $|Y|=\kappa^{+}$ and $[Y]^{2}\subset E(\alpha,\beta)$ for some fixed $\alpha,\beta$, contradicting $s(X)\leq\kappa$. I am sure I am overlooking something trivial, but where exactly am I relying on the assumption of $T_1$ ?
Thanks in advance for any clarification !

I think, you already mentioned the crucial point: how do you define pseudo-base in the absence of $T_1$?

Oh, I see. If X is $T_1$ then any base is a pseudo-base so, in particular, pseudo-bases exist.

So you know the answer to your question?

I suppose so. If $X$ is not $T_1$ then I can't guarantee the existence of the collections $\mathcal{B}(x)$ for each $x\in X$. Thanks for the clarification!

You not even can't guarantee it, but if each point has a pseudo base as usually defined, then the space is $T_1$. This was the reason, why I asked you, how you define pseudo base.
